# Retrieving a Portion of Webpage Code using URLFetch

Tags: performance-tuning, html, searching, web-access

The `URLFetch` command is very useful for pulling the entire html source of a given webpage, however, if one wanted to speed up the process, by only requesting a ***portion*** of the page, for instance, only the body, how would one do this?  A given page of html might be quite large, and querying several pages in sequence could slow the process down significantly, if all one really wants is a small portion of that page.

At present, it is possible to specify: `"Content"`, `"ContentData"`, `"Headers"`, `"Cookies"`, `"StatusCode"`.  I thought that `"Content"` would pull only the body portion, excluding the headers, but this is not the case.

Alternatively, is it possible to request a specific ***line or lines*** from within the html code?

Comment: The size of the headers is very small compared to the time it takes to establish a connection with the server. I don't think there is anything you can do to reduce the size of the request enough for it to matter, but you might be interested in `URLFetchAsynchrounous` which allows you to download many pages simultaneously.

Comment: @Pickett  Fair point, what are your thoughts on the second part of my question, that is trying to extract a specific line or lines from the html code?  `URLFetchAsynchronous` I agree is much faster, and I'd prefer to use it, however, I am pulling pages based on the results of the prior page, so it appears to be inherently sequential.

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible, unfortunately.

Comment: Before `URLFetch` I used to use *wget* regularly. You might want to consider trying it if you are having problems with `URLFetch`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch How do you call `wget` from Mathematica?

Comment: I used to mostly run it directly from the Terminal (OS X) but you can also run it via a command like `Run` from within Mma